# Print value from a lua table if pattern matches

Tags: regex, lua, minecraft, lua-table, lua-patterns

Okay, so I just recently got into lua and find myself stuck with the following:

I have the function peripheral.getNames() (which is a custom function)

it will return a table with the structure key,value, whereas key is always a number and starts from 1 and value will be what the function finds (it searches for devices connected to it)

In my example it creates a table which looks like this

```
1 herp
2 derp
3 monitor_1
4 morederp
```

I can print the values with the following

```
local pgn = peripherals.getNames()

for key,value in pairs(pgn) do
 setCursorPos(1,key)
 write(value)
 end
end
```

this will output the corresponding value of the table at key on my display like this

```
herp
derp
monitor_1
morederp
```

now, I try to filter my results so it only prints something if value contains 'monitor'

I tried to achive this with

```
for key,value in pairs(pgn) do
 if string.match(value, monitor) then
 #dostuff
 end
end
```

but it always returns 'bad argument: string expected, got nil'
so obviously string.match either does not accept 'value' or, value is not a string
so i tried converting value first

```
for key,value in pairs(pgn) do
 value = tostring(value)
  if ....
 #dostuff
 end
end
```

but it still throws the same error

Do any of you have an idea how i might either get string.match to accept 'value' or if there is another method to check the contents of 'value' for a pattern while in this for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is talking about the variable `monitor`, which is not defined and so has a nil value.

Try `string.match(value, "monitor")`.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I should get a coffee...didn't know I had to use quotation marks for the specified pattern.