# Pattern match a variable using Lua

Tags: regex, lua, match

Evening all,

I'm looking at passing text from a monitoring system as a variable and then using the regex/LUA to look for duplicate usernames

Example line of text is:

```
Unathorised Change Profile Entries: (Audit trail entry) USERNAME - USERNAME
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check [`if(string.match(str, "(%w+) %- %1$")) then
  print("Matching!")
end`](http://ideone.com/RHThad).

Comment: Almost there! Looks great! Thank you.  I'm passing the variable text from some alert text, here's my test:

Comment: a = alarm.get ("VD27075360-92047")

str = a

if(string.match(str, "(%w+) %- %1$")) then
  print("Matching!")

end

Comment: You may adjust the pattern, say, instead of `%w` use `%a` to match just letters. If the spaces are not obligatory, use `*` quantifier after each of them.

Comment: Geting this: Error in line 5: bad argument #1 to 'match' (string expected, got table)

Comment: You  can only run a regex on a string variable.

Comment: hmm, it should be a string variable as far as I'm aware

Comment: Here's what I have at the moment: a = alarm.get ("VD27075360-92047")

str = a

if(string.match(str, "(%w+) %- %1$")) then
  print("Matching!")

end

Comment: You are stll not passing a *string*, see [Print value from a lua table if pattern matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252653/print-value-from-a-lua-table-if-pattern-matches).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134608/discussion-between-greenage-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you for the help above.

Here's my final working code:

a = alarm.get ()

str = a

if (string.match(a.message, "(%a+) %- %1$")) then 
    print("Matching!")

else
      print("No match")
end